# Array of different sizes

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using this formula and I am getting some troubles in there:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="","",IF($B$2:$B>=Helper!$B$2:$B,1,0)))

B2:B Column Main sheet contains almost 30k rows with values and Helper2 B column sheet has only 60 values but the sheet has 1000 rows.

I am checking whether the values in B (Main sheet) are greater or equals to what I have in the Helper B column. But I am only getting the results for the first 1000 rows in the main sheet.

can anyone please tell me what is the workaround for this?

ERROR is: Array arguments to GTE are of different sizes.

Thanks

Here is the link to the Spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hfXCFTp_vLqPFjazM-Vo6-3o8J1td1zpnCJOeK1LBg0/edit#gid=511305173

[Main sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkWOq.png)

[Helper2 Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rLn0.png)

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Can you please send a request? I ll give you the access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that both sheets have unequal number of rows. (`GTE` in the error means greater than equal which is the conditional you used)

Easiest fix to eliminate the error is to have the same number of rows from both sheets. If your `Main` sheet have 30000 and `Helper2` have 1000, then add 29000 to your `Helper2` sheet.

But if you want to limit your `ARRAYFORMULA` and only compare until row 1000, then limit the range. Use the formula below:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A1000="","",IF($B$2:$B>=Helper2!$B$2:$B,1,0)))
```

Or use `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` to limit the result of your `ARRAYFORMULA`

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="","",IF($B$2:$B>=Helper2!$B$2:$B,1,0))), 999, 1)
```

- Limits to 999 rows (since you started at row 2, 1000th row in sheets should be the 999th row of `ARRAYFORMULA` result)

#### EDIT:

Try this one:

```
=arrayformula(if(A2:A="","",if((B2:B <= vlookup(A2:A, Helper2!$A$2:$B, 2)) * (C2:C >= vlookup(A2:A, Helper2!$A$2:$B, 2)) > 0 = TRUE, 1, 0)))
```

#### Note:

- Your data has issue with your Artem name, not sure why. Thus if Artem is found, blank is returned.
- Tried changing all "Artem" to "John" and the formula works seamlessly.

Comment: Sure I ll try both of these and let you know .. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Hi @FawadAnsari, was the answer above able to fix your issue?

Comment: HI @NaziA, Nops the solution is not working. The formula is finishing till the range I give in the formula but I need to put it for all the values in the Main sheet.

Comment: Can you plz send me the request? so that I can give you access to the sheet?

Comment: Shared with you

Comment: I have commented on the sheet. 
for Patrik, it should be 1 rather than 0 because the date 2019-01 is = 2019-01 in cell B2